How to continue the jquery function on another page
On a button click run the function
for example $('.div1').show();
from a page
and the above function needs to run along with another functions on other few pages until click a second button on any of those pages.
Any or All help welcome.

It's not at all clear from the question what is required. Attach the code or explain in more detail.

Some options: pass a parameter on the url. cookie (least recommended).  session storage,  local storage

Your problem/task is not explained with enough details, please read [ask], then [edit] with a [mre].

@guriev - on a button click run the code as said in the query $('.div1').show(); and these code should run on another page under some other functions that already running until a second button clicks from the first page or on all those available pages with the same button.

you can push a cookie with flag 'runRequired' & execute the function on page load until your flag is true
